# Modifying displayed date format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I modify the displayed date format in my database view to exclude the timestamp (00:00:00) and show only the date in the format (DD/MM/YYYY)?

```
<td>@marks["Test_Date"]</td>
```

I am fetching date here and i have tried like this

```
<td>@((DateTime)marks["Test_Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")</td>
```

It didn't work it just print the date like this
20/02/2024 00:00:00.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")

Comment: What is the **exact** data-type of your date column in your database? Are you aware that `date`/`datetime`/`datetimeoffset`/`time` columns are a _binary_ representation and so are not saved with any particular "format", right?

Comment: @Dai its Date Datatype in my db I am using SQL server

Comment: If that was the case `DateTime.ToString()` would work. Dates have no format, either in the database or C#. They're binary values. What is the type of the actual value stored in `marks["Test_Date"]`? What is `marks`? I suspect you're loading the date as a *string* instead of an actual DateTime. Or that the database column is a text column

Comment: If, as I suspect, `marks["Test_Date"]` is a string, it would be safer to extract the first 10 characters instead of trying to parse the string without knowing the actual text format. `04/07//2024` can be both July 4th and April 7th

Answer (score 1):

If you want to format a `DateTime` value with a custom format, you must follow the rules laid out by the [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). For instance, the character `/` is used to indicate "The date separator", which may turn out to be another character than `/`, depending on the executing process' underlying locale.

If you want to force the format to use `/` you can escape it:

```
new DateTime(2024, 2, 20).ToString("dd\/MM\/yyyy");
```

This expression produces the string `"20/02/2024"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In formatting operations, custom date and time format strings can be used either with the ToString method of a date and time instance or with a method that supports composite formatting. The following example illustrates both uses.

DateTime thisDate1 = new DateTime(2011, 6, 10);
Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");

DateTimeOffset thisDate2 = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 6, 10, 15, 24, 16,
                                              TimeSpan.Zero);
Console.WriteLine("The current date and time: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}",
                   thisDate2);
```